# find a specific json by id

Tags: javascript

I have several json vars with the name of `"jsonObject_" + id`, for example:

```
var jsonObject_123 = ...;

var jsonObject_456 = ...;
```

etc. All those jsons have the same format, same keys, but different values.

I also have a method that receives the id as argument.

I need to change the correct jsonObject address according to the id. That is, if the argument is `123`, I need to change `jsonObject_123.address`

How can I get the reference to `jsonObject_123` based on the id argument?

Comment: Why are those variables not in an object?

Comment: FYI These are not "JSON objects". These are plain JavaScript objects. JSON always is a string - it's a *transport format* - as soon as you are dealing with actual objects it's not JSON anymore.

Comment: So many related questions/duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+variable+variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a small remark about the terminology used here. What you are calling *JSON vars* has nothing to do with JSON. Those are plain javascript variables. [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a serialization format.

Now depending on the scope where those variables are defined you could use the following:

```
var id = '123';
window['jsonObject_' + id].address = 'some address';
```

In this example I have assumed that those variables are declared in the global scope => you could access them through the `window` object. You will have to adapt this code depending on your specific case.

But a better approach would be to group all those variables into a containing object:

```
var jsonObject = {};
jsonObject['123'] = { address: 'address 1' };
jsonObject['456'] = { address: 'address 2' };
...
```

and then when you want to access it:

```
jsonObject['123'].address = 'some new address';
```

Comment: Did you get some error? Because `it didn't work` is not a very precise problem description. Also here's a full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qy2MJ/

Comment: no, it just didn't change the value. same thing happened when I changed the function so instead of the id I'll send the entire json - it didn't change the value at all. it just remained the same. Regarding your idea to create an array of jsons - I create those jsons dynamically according to user's actions, so I can't create such an array

Comment: The array can be created dynamically. You could add values to the `jsonObject` dynamically based on user actions. I guess you will have to show your real code if you need more help because I suspect that the code you have shown here is not related to the problem.

Comment: You are right, of course. once I've changed the code to work as you suggested (to create an array of jsons and to add to it the jsonObject dynamically) - everything worked just fine. Thanks, Darin!